# Java string input and output string

Tags: java, string, println

and thanks for reading this question from a beginner.

I tried to run this code on the command:

```
public class a{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] s = args;
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

and the following input: "java a this is string"

gives me:

"[Ljava.lang.String;@65d4ab0e" as an output.

What should I do to get "this is string" as output?

Comment: `s` is an *array*, which is an *object*, and in Java since each object has `toString()` method, the default is displaying the class name representation, then adding `@` sign and then the hashcode.. You *don't* want to print the object, but its content, use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-) method.

Comment: There are a couple of options. Easiest Arrays.toString(s);  other option is to loop through your string array and print each member in turn. The output you see it's a representation of the array object, not it's members. Confusing if coming from some other languages, but logical once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the array object itself, not the content of the array.
The hashcode value `[Ljava.lang.String;@65d4ab0e` indicates that, s is an array and it's has String values. The leading `[` says, the object you have printed is an array.

```
public class a{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] s = args;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a way to print the array, but the output is not the expected one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Arrays.toString(s)`

Take a look at  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])

Comment: This is a way to print the array, but the output is not the expected one.